# Filtering out a class members with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, syntax

It's probably a simple problem, but I've only just started coding, plz bear with me...

I have a bunch of elements, with all the same two classes, partWiel and partWielIn. I want to remove the second class from all of them, except the first.

Basically, this is what I want, but I think I can't use mathematical operators inside those square brackets:
`partWiel[>0].classList.remove("partWielIn");`

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Something like `document.querySelectorAll('. partWiel').forEach((el, i) => if (i > 0) el.classList.remove('partWiel'))`. See [*classList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and the [*NodeList#forEach* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) which is implemented by the NodeList returned by *querySelectorAll*.

Comment: @RobG You can not do that, It gives an error, because requires the brackets `{}` if the first statement is `if`. Like this: `document.querySelectorAll('. partWiel').forEach((el, i) => {if (i > 0) el.classList.remove('partWiel')})`

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal It is not the forEach that requires the {} it is that the first statement is  `if`

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with this

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".partWiel")] // get all partWiel into an array
  .slice(1) // drop the first
  .forEach(part => part.classList.remove("partWielIn")); // remove from the rest
```

```css
.partWiel {
  background-color: red
}

.partWielIn {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="partWiel partWielIn">partWiel</li>
  <li class="partWiel partWielIn">partWiel</li>
  <li class="partWiel partWielIn">partWiel</li>
  <li class="partWiel partWielIn">partWiel</li>
  <li class="partWiel partWielIn">partWiel</li>
  <li class="partWiel partWielIn">partWiel</li>
  <li class="partWiel partWielIn">partWiel</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".partWiel");

elements.forEach(function (element, index) {
    if (index != 0) {
        element.classList.remove("partWielIn");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1- First you select all the elements with "partWiel" class:

```
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.partWiel');
```

2- Loop over the elements and remove "partWeilIn" class from all elements except the first:

```
for(let i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].classList.remove("partWielIn")
}
```

Comment: You should use `let i = 1;`

Comment: Of course, just iterate through it again. Perfect, thank you!